Getting a compatibility error when building Docker for Strapi
I have a Strapi CMS install that when I build a Docker, the yarn install command errors with the following error:
application.co.uk-strapi@0.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.18.1". Got "12.20.1"  

However I have the engine defined in the package.json...
"engines": {
   "node": ">=14.18.1",
   "npm": ">=6.14.0"
},
"engineStrict": true,

...and nvm is running the current version of 14.19.3
% nvm current
v14.19.3

I can't seem to find where it is getting the 12.20.1 from. Is there something obvious I am missing?  Where is the docker build getting 12.20.1 from as the current node version.
I also have a .nvmrc file with v14.19.3 in.

You should define node version in your Docker file, so your Dockerfile should be like:
# Node.js Docker image
FROM node:14.18.1

# create the directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy project files from local machine to the workdir in container
COPY . .

# run npm install in our local machine
RUN npm ci

# build project
RUN npm run build

# expose the listening port
EXPOSE 1337

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

